How can I get data about wallet transactions as efficiently as possible?
I need to process wallets to get information about the necessary transactions, but in order to find the ones I need, I have to send a request to receive all transactions or a certain bundle, which is very expensive for free rpcs and it turns out that to process 100 transactions, I need to spend 100 requests, maybe there are some apis or sorting that would return the transactions that fall under my criteria
